# Density function estimation from histogram with infinite bin

Tags: density-function, kernel-smoothing, density-estimation

Given a histogram such as the following

#### Histogram [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram#Examples)

| Bin | Count |
| --- | --- |
| −3.5 to −2.51 | 9 |
| −2.5 to −1.51 | 32 |
| −1.5 to −0.51 | 109 |
| −0.5 to 0.49 | 180 |
| 0.5 to 1.49 | 132 |
| 1.5 to Inf | 38 |

What would be the best approach to estimating a probability density function from the data? I am particularly having trouble since the last bucket is a range to positive infinity.

Comment: To fit a distribution, you first have to posit a *family* of distributions, such as Normal, (shifted) Gamma, etc.  Maximum Likelihood is a standard approach.  It is described [in several threads here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=bin+maximum+likelihood+estimate+distribution+normal).  At https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/68238/919 I explain this and provide working code.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I understand that in the ideal case you would use a maximum likelihood estimation but I wanted to approach this without having to posit a family of distributions. Is there an approach that is produces a distribution (potentially non differentiable) that is a rough estimation of the given histogram. I was thinking to "connect" the midpoint of each bin linearly as this approximates (albeit mildly) a continuous version of the histogram.

Comment: Without more structure, there are very many ways in which this can be done. If you can't suggest a family of distributions, can you give a clue as to your purpose in contriving a density function that might have produced these data.

Comment: My end goal is to estimate the mean, median, variance and standard deviation of the original histogram. I was using a density function as a way to give me a better approximation of those values

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are a few of my thoughts about your data. I hope some of them will be useful.

To a good approximation, your data can be summarized as frequencies `f` and discrete
values `v`, corresponding to your six intervals, as shown below. Values are midpoints of the intervals, with arbitrary value
$2.5$ for the last (open-ended) interval)

```
v = c(-3:1, 2.5); f = c(9,32,109,180,132,38)
v
[1] -3.0 -2.0 -1.0  0.0  1.0  2.5
f
[1]   9  32 109 180 132  38
```

Then the sample size is $n = 500,$ and the approximate mean `a` and standard
deviation
`s` as shown below:

```
 n = sum(f); n
 [1] 500
 a = sum(f*v)/n; a
 [1] 0.054
 s = sqrt(sum(f*(v-a)^2)/(n-1)); s
 [1] 1.172533
```

I have simulated a sample that might have come from the
same population, by spreading values uniformly in each of the middle four
intervals and using beta distributions that put relatively fewer
points at the extremes than uniform. Your final interval is split
into two intervals of length $1.$

```
x = c(-3.5+rbeta(9,2,1), runif(32,-2.5,-1.5),
      runif(104,-1.5,-.5), runif(180,-.5,.5),
      runif(132,.5,1.5), 1.5+2*rbeta(38,1,2))
```

The histogram below shows the
results for intervals, the `rug` along the horizontal axis
shows locations of the 500 simulated points, and output
for a 'non-plotted' histogram shows bin frequencies.
(Notice that the count $38$ in your open-ended interval
has been split over two bins $27+11.)$

```
cutp = seq(-3.5, 3.5, 1)
hist(x, prob=T, br = cutp, col="skyblue2")
 rug(x)
hist(x, br = cutp, plot=F)$counts
[1]   9  32 104 180 132  27  11
```

[image]

The histogram seems to have a vaguely normal shape and
the normal curve with appropriate mean and standard deviation is
a reasonably good fit.
(See the dotted density curve in the figure below.)

```
A = mean(x);  S = sd(x);  A;  S
[1] 0.03776537
[1] 1.152983
curve(dnorm(x, A, S), add=T, lwd=3, lty="dotted", col="darkgreen")
```

Finally, I used the [kernel density estimation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation) (KDE) procedure `density` in R to see a possible
continuous distribution corresponding to the simulated data. The default kernel
type in R is gaussian. Roughly speaking, this KDE is a mixture of normal distributions over various
intervals (unrelated to the histogram). The length of these intervals is called
the *bandwidth* of the KDE; to get a smoother KDE, I have used a slightly wider bandwidth than
the default in R, with `adj=1.2`. (See the brown density curve in
the figure below.) In R, the KDE is represented by 512 $(x,y)$ pairs, which may
be displayed using `$`-notation `density(x,adj=1.5)$x` and `density(x,adj1.5)$y`
(not shown).

```
lines(density(x,adj=1.5), col="brown")
```

[image]

*Note:* Bear in mind that a different seed at the beginning, might have
'reconstructed' the data in a slightly different way, leading to a slightly
different KDE. You can try several runs, omitting the `set.seed` statement.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question already received an answer and the results seem really nice (+1)! However I would like to mention also another approach to solve this problem (a similar question was actually asked [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/298703/constructing-probability-density-distributions-out-of-cumulative-data-of-bins-an/498030#498030)). From these frequencies associated to coarse bins, I would estimate the 'implied' density using the penalized composite link histogram smoothing technique proposed in [Eilers2007](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/10.1177/1471082X0700700302) (in the answer to the question I mentioned above I summarized the main idea behind the approach).

There is a R implementation of this method in the package `JOPS`. The code below produces a smooth density estimator from your binned data taking the last bin equal to $[1.5, 30]$. You can play with the upper limit if you want. The shape of the fitted density should hardly change (however the shape of the empirical histogram would be affected of course).

I hope this helps and is interesting for you.

```r
library(JOPS)
library(colorout)
library(ggplot2)

# Data
xl  = c(-3.5, -2.5, -1.5, -0.5, 0.5, 1.5) 
xr  = c(-2.51, -1.51, -0.51, 0.49, 1.49, 30)
y   = c(9, 32, 109, 180, 132, 38)

# Set-ups
m    = length(y)
n    = 500
wdts = xr - xl 
dens = y/wdts/sum(y)

# Composition matrix C  1 if finer bin is included in the coarse one, 0 otherwise
x = seq(min(xl)-3, max(xr) + 3, len = n)
C = matrix(0, m, n)
for(i in 1:m) C[i, x >= xl[i] & x <= xr[i]] = 1

# Prepare B-splines bases
B = JOPS::bbase(x, nseg = 30)

# Fit
mod = JOPS::pclm(y, C, B, lambda = 5, pord = 2, show = T)
est = mod$gamma / diff(x)[1] / sum(mod$gamma)

# Plot
fit = data.frame(x = x, fits = est)
dat = data.frame(xl = xl, xr = xr, y = dens)
plt = ggplot(dat, aes(ymin = 0)) + 
    geom_rect(aes(xmin = xl, xmax = xr, ymax = y, fill = I('white'), color = I('black'))) +
    geom_line(aes(x = x, y = fits), data = fit, col = I('red')) + 
    ylab('Density') +
    theme_bw()

plt
```

[image]